# How to add layers to a selection in Visio 2007 VBA?

Tags: vba, svg, visio

I want to export certain layers to svg through VBA in Visio 2007.

I am getting stuck on adding the layers to the selection. How do I do this?

```
Sub tester()

Dim Layer    As Visio.Layer
Dim Layers   As Visio.Layers
Dim sel      As Visio.Selection

Dim filename As String
Dim lyrName   As String
Dim iLays     As Integer

Set Layers = Application.ActivePage.Layers
Set sel = EmptySelection 'Or whatever empty initialization neeeds to happen...

For iLays = 1 To Layers.Count

    Set Layer = Layers(iLays)
    lyrName = Layer.Name

    If lyrName = "Walls" Or lyrName = "Zones" Then
        sel.AddLayer (lyrName) 'or some such nonsense - This is broked.
    End If

    filename = Application.ActiveDocument.Path & "PootyStuff.svg"
    'Export the page as svg file
    sel.Export filename

Next iLays

Set Layer = Nothing
Set Layers = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub tester()  
Dim sel As Visio.Selection
Dim filename As String
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
' create selection by layers
Set sel = ActivePage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeByLayer, visSelModeSkipSuper, "Walls;Zones")
filename = Application.ActiveDocument.Path & "PootyStuff.svg"
'Export the page as svg file
sel.Export filename
End Sub
```